# Can scala compiler enforce to implement abstract trait methods when mixin in?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, mixins, traits, abstract-methods

I have a trait with abstract methods and concrete implemented methods, so something like this:

```
trait MyTrait extends BaseClass {
    def myAbstractMethod: MyReturnType
    def myConcreteMethod = { /*implementation*/ }
}
```

Now I mixin the trait:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass with MyTrait {

}
```

The BaseClass does not implement the abstract method. I expected the scala compiler to enforce that the abstract method must be implemented (just like a Java interface) when I mix in the trait. But there is no compiler error.

My particular case is more complicated. I was not able to test what happens at runtime, yet.

1. Why doesn't the scala compiler enforce the implementation of the abstract method?
2. Can I make the scala compiler enforce the implementation of the abstract method?
3. Must I add abstract or override somewhere?
4. What happens at runtime when I try to create and use instances of MyClass?

Comment: I've just encountered this when I had other errors in the same file/project (but not in other projects in the workspace). I'm using Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) with Scala 4.2.0. I've reported this as a bug: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets/1002604-no-compile-error-for-not-implementing-abstract-methods-(when-other-errors-exist-in-the-file-project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely get a compiler error...

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait MyTrait extends BaseClass {
    def myAbstractMethod: MyReturnType
    def myConcreteMethod = { /*implementation*/ }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass with MyTrait {    
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:14: error: class MyClass needs to be abstract, since method myAbstractMethod in trait MyTrait of type => MyReturnType is not defined
       class MyClass extends BaseClass with MyTrait {


 ^
```

Comment: That is strange. I work with Scala IDE for Eclipse and there is no such compiler error in the classes / traits we talk about. I was making major refactorings and had some compiler errors, but only in some other classes completely independent from the one we talk about. Now that I completely commented out those errornous classes there are new errors coming up in the relevant traits. Seems like the eclipse scala plugin or something did not handle this as I expected.